# Зеркальный градиент

Tags: css3, html, css, graphics

Здраствуйте. Как можно реализовать зеркальный градиент? Что то типа такого: [image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Есть хороший сервис который предоставляет возможность редактирования градиентов и имеет удобный и понятный интерфейс. http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/